# How to hide html when cookies have a value

Tags: javascript, html, cookies

```
<html>
<head>
<title>
</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
function createCookie(newCookie)
    {
    var expDate = new Date()
    expDate.setYear(expDate.getYear() + 1);
    var cookieVal = document.getElementById(newCookie).value;
    document.cookie = newCookie + " = " + cookieVal + "<br />";
}

</script>
</head>
<body>
Please enter your email<input type="text" id="email" onblur="createCookie('email');" /><br />
Please enter your address<input type="text" id="address" onblur="createCookie('address');" /><br />
Please enter your phone number<input type="text" id="phone" onblur="createCookie('phone');" /><br />

<script type="text/javascript">
    document.write("EveryCookie: " + document.cookie);
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

My question is, is there a way that I can hide the HTML inputs when my cookies have a value so that JUST the cookies are seen, and if the cookies have no value the HTML inputs are again displayed.

Comment: Wrap the inputs with a `div`. Check cookie in javascript, then hide the `div` as desired.

Comment: _"so that JUST the cookies are seen"_ - Do you mean you want to show the _values_ that were stored in your cookies?

Answer (score 0):

Step 1:
      Check the Cookie value first if it has values then

Step 2: 
       Using javascript function hide the element by its id.

```
 In javascript:

 document.getElementById('thinktohide').style.display = 'none';

 In html:

<input type ='text' id="thinktohide">
```

Step 2: 
       Even if you want the element back when cookie is not having value you can show that.